# Deixar componente seguindo o padrão do CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3, revisão-de-código

Como eu posso melhorar esta CakePHP 3.0 `Component` (no interior da pasta controller)

> Pergunta discutida em: [Postar código funcional no stackoverflow visando uma refatoração?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4619/postar-c%C3%B3digo-funcional-no-stackoverflow-visando-uma-refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

**1º:** para usar libs externas (armazenados na pasta **vendor**) Eu estou usando a palavra-chave `require` e incluo a classe usando`palavra-chave use`, como este:

> ```
> require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');
> ```

e

> ```
> use ImageTool;
> ```

**2º:** no método `saveFileLFS` eu estou usando `true` e `false` para marcar se a operação ocorreu com sucesso.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Component;

require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');

use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use ImageTool;

class UploadFileComponent extends Component
{
    function resizeImage($settings)
    {
        $status = ImageTool::resize([
            'input' => $settings['input'],
            'output' => $settings['output'],
            'width' => $settings['width'],
            'height' => $settings['height'],
            'mode' => $settings['mode']
        ]);
        return $status;
    }

    public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
    {
        $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
            $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
        if(StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
            file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
            return true;
        }else
       {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puts! Burzum, aquela banda de black metal que o cara matou o outro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Se você tiver outro ponto onde possa ser melhorado, comente ou responda a esta pergunta**

Para mudar o `require` eu usei o `composer.json` `classmap` desta forma (vejam esta resposta: [Import Class without autoload and repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090241/import-vendor-class-in-cakephp-3-without-require)):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "./vendor/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component"
    ]
}
```

Não é necessário o `require` agora.

Em `saveFileLFS` método agora estou usando `Exceptions` se algo não funcionar.

```
public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
{
    $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
        $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
    if(!StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
        file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
        throw new MissingHelperException();
        //Or other Exception
    }
}
```